# Customise Meta Titles in CP (Admin) Pages

Tags: control-panel, admin, title, custom, meta

So I've been customising the admin area with styling and low key branding - but cannot find any way of editing the meta titles, so am currently stuck with *Login | ExpressionEngine* etc in the `<title></title>` of every admin page. Does anyone know how to change this? Ideally I'd like it to say *Login | NameOfMySite* etc, so the client feels happy.

Any help appreciated, I've looked all over, with no luck.

Comment: I've not seen this done. I imagine you'd have to modify some of the core CP theme files to do so, which I wouldn't recommend. Perhaps you could write a quick extension to swap it out?

Comment: Huh. Ive never written an extension, maybe I'll look into that! Yes, I think the only way to do this is to edit core files, never a good solution. One of the reasons I'd like to do this is because when you make a Fluid app from the site to give to the client, it would look much better if the titles were consistent and branded.

Comment: You may be breaking the license in doing so. The license states > All copyright and proprietary notices and logos in the Control Panel and within the Software files must remain intact.
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/license.html The title tag isn't explicitly described, but if it applies to logo I assume it applies to the title too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and created an accessory to rewrite the title tag using JavaScript. its not the best solution but it did the job. Maybe you could build on it to make it better. Follow the instructions [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/accessories.html) for creating an accessory and add this code as the set_sections.

```
function set_sections()
{
    $meta_title = implode(" | ", array_filter(array($this->EE->view->cp_page_title, $this->EE->config->config['site_label'])));
    $js = "$('title').html('{$meta_title}');";
    $this->EE->cp->add_to_foot('<script type="text/javascript">'.$js.'</script>');
}
```